# Database architecture for payment management application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, architecture, polymorphism, associations

```
              Items -> ReservationWithItems -> Checkout -> Payment -> User
Course -> Attendes -> RegistrationForCourse -> Checkout -> Payment -> User
                                  YearlyFee -> Checkout -> Payment -> User
```

I want to create application with handles reservations, yearly fees and training courses in my mountain club. I would like to organize my code to use Checkout class which will collect products like reservation or yearly fee or registration for course and then I will be able to create payment for them.

Below is my idea how to achieve that but I am not sure if I should use polymorphism here.

```
Db::Item(name:, cost:)
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservations_items

Db::ReservationsItems
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :reservation

Db::Reservation(description:, state:, start_date:, end_date:)
  has_many :items, through: :reservations_items
  belong_to :payable, polymorphic: true

Db::Checkout
  has_many :reservations, as: :payable
  has_many :yearly_fees, as: :payable
  has_one :payment
  belongs_to :user

Db::Payment
  belongs_to :checkout

-----

Db::YearlyFee(cost:, :year)
  belong_to :payable, polymorphic: true
```

Are there somewhere best practices or examples for this kind of systems?